# The old syntax for showing payload options in msfvenom does not work

Tags: metasploit

I've tried so many times with different syntax to display the payload options in msfvenom. However, I cannot get it to run.

Version 1.

```
[*] exec: msfvenom -p windows/shell/bind_tcp --payload-options

Error: Missing required argument for option
MsfVenom - a Metasploit standalone payload generator.
Also a replacement for msfpayload and msfencode.
Usage: /usr/bin/msfvenom [options] <var=val>
```

Version 2.

```
[*] exec: msfvenom -p windows/x64/vncinject/reverse_winhttps -o

Error: Missing required argument for option
MsfVenom - a Metasploit standalone payload generator.
Also a replacement for msfpayload and msfencode.
Usage: /usr/bin/msfvenom [options] <var=val>
```

How does it exactly work? Have I typed it wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the options have been updated. Use:

```
./msfvenom -p windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp --list-options
```

You can also start msfconsole, select the payload and then use:

```
show options
show advanced
show evasions
```

etc to show further detailed options about the payload you have selected.

Comment: a side note for anyone who might look into this:
It will show "permission denied" when you type in the command prompt straght away. 
However, It works when typing in msfconsole.

Comment: @ShanHuang The access denied issue you are facing with msfvenom is due to the OS and the user you are using. For example, if you are using a debian based OS and not using root, you might have to sudo msfvenom.